# Cannot retrieve data from Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

I created a new Blazor application with Azure AD authentication. Login functionality works as expected. Now I need to retrieve a list of users of a particular group. On Azure AD, I created a Client Secret. Also, I added Microsoft.Graph permissions Directory.Read.All, Group.Read.All, and
GroupMember.Read.All, and granted admin consent for the permissions.

Here are the permissions:

[image]

Here is my code I use to retrieve the users of a group:

```
            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(_adSettings.ClientId)
            .WithAuthority($"{_adSettings.Instance}/{_adSettings.TenantId}/ v2.0")
            .WithClientSecret(_adSettings.ClientSecret)
            .Build();

        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {
            // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
            var authResult = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        }));

            var members = await graphServiceClient.Groups["mygroup@mydomain.com"]
                .Members
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

The last statement throws an exception:

> An error occurred sending the request. HttpStatusCode: 404: NotFound

I tried to replace it with

```
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

But result was the same.

Comment: Hi, how's going?Has your issue got resolved ?

Comment: @Stanley Gong I have some permissions issues. I am waiting from our IT to resolve them, to be able to try your suggestion. Sorry for the delay, I did not forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify your group object ID instead of the group name:
[image]

My test group:
[image]

Test code and result:
[image]

UPDATE:

This is a C# console app code for this test, hope it helps :

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;



namespace graphsdktest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var clientId = "<Azure AD App ID>";
            var clientSecret = "<App secret>";
            var tenantID = "<tenant ID>";
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

            var result = graphClient.Groups["<group ID>"].Members.Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            foreach (var user in result) {
                Console.WriteLine(user.Id);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

If you get some permission exception while you query members of a group, pls go to Azure AD => App registrations => find your app => API permissions => Add a permission => Microsoft graph api => application permission => `GroupMember.Read.All` :
[image]

And click This button to finish the grant process :
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: I tried it. It did not compile with this error: 'IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'. So I used it like this: var members = await graphServiceClient.Groups["532dc7t2-991e-48wd-be62-44d920945ef5"]            .Members.Request().GetAsync(); This gives me the same exception. When I use await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();, the result is the same.

Comment: @DavidShochet, thanks for the update.It is weird, I am not sure the root reason about it. Anyway, I have appended all my code in my answer, it is a simple console app which works perfectly for me, hope it helps :)

Comment: I can't figure out where Microsoft.Graph.Auth comes from. I don't see such a Nuget package, and it is not recognized.

Comment: Found it in pre-release. Got the following error: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. Any idea?

Comment: @DavidShochet, this is a common error that due to you have not grant group member read permission to your Azure AD App, I have appended details about how to grant this permission

Comment: But I do have this permission. I mentioned it in my question. Just added a picture of it.

Comment: @DavidShochet, From the picture,your admin granted your app with Delegated type Group member read all, it is for users,you are using an application to get access token, please ask your admin to grant Application type permission to your application. As you can see in my last capture, the type of group member read all  is Application not Delegated.

Comment: I changed it to Application, and granted consent, and yet the result is the same: insufficient privileges.

Comment: I changed the picture of my permissions.

Comment: I realized that was trying to use a wrong tenant. Now it works! thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidShochet,glad to know your issue has been solved:)